# Keyboard language change not working in PhpStorm on Windows 7

Tags: phpstorm

I am using **PhpStorm** 8.0.3 on **windows 7**. It is fine for me against to other IDEs that I previously used such as Dreamweaver and sublime. But it has strange problem for me.

I use two languages English and Persian. When writing code in **English** language there is no problem. But when I change language to **Persian** by <kbd>Shift + Alt</kbd> (for writing Persian text), I can not change back to English and I have to restart **PhpStorm** for solving this problem!

Of course this problem is not permanent and occurs only sometimes.

Who can give a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ATM there is no solution to resolve this from the IDE side. You can read the whole thread here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6290

### Workaround:

Assign additional shortcut for specific language (English in this case).

In Windows' Language Bar - Settings... - Advanced Key Settings - To English (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl + 0</kbd>)

---

**NOTE:** *this issue has been fixed since Windows 8* (yes, by Microsoft). I cannot reproduce it on my current Windows 10 Pro 20H2 ENG.